# Why does completing the square work?

Tags: linear-algebra, completing-the-square

I am currently learning about quadratics in high school and we've just done completing the square. Now I understand *how* to complete the square, I just don't understand *why* we can complete the square.

This is the generic complete the square formula

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$

$x^2 + \frac{b}a x + \frac{c}a = 0$

$(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}a = 0$

$(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}a$

$x + \frac{b}{2a} = \frac{b}{2a} \pm \sqrt{\frac{c}a}$

$x = \frac{b}{2a} - \frac{b}{2a} \pm \sqrt{\frac{c}a}$

$x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{c}a}$

*NB: I hope I got this right; I'm more used to numbers. If not, feel free to correct*

And, as I find it easier to spot mistakes, a numerical example.

$2x^2 - 4x - 16 = 0$

$x^2 - 2x - 8 = 0$

$(x - 1)^2 - 1 - 8 = 0$

$(x - 1)^2 - 9 = 0$

$(x - 1)^2 = 9$

$x - 1 = \pm 3$

$x = 1 \pm 3$

What I don't understand is why line 3 works and how it can produce the correct answer. I don't see how we can divide it by 2 and then subtract its square.

My math teacher didn't really explain this as it's probably beyond what we have to learn but is there anyone who can tell me how this works?

Comment: Expand the square to see how completing the square works.

Comment: You have numerous typos along the way here (missing constants, missing $x$s, etc.), including in line 3. Perhaps just cleaning those up will help you. At any rate, the one step that I am totally not seeing here is going from $x^2+\frac{b}{a} x + \frac{c}{a}$ to $x^2+\frac{b}{a} x + \frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}{a}$. Do you see why you can make that change? (Notice that my third and fourth terms cancel each other out).

Comment: `What I don't understand is why line 3 works` That's because your line $3$ is wrong as written.

Comment: @Ian I have written a note underneath. If it's wrong please follow the note.

Comment: You do know that $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ dont you?  So $x^2 + px +w = 0$ means $x^2 + 2(\frac p2)x +w = 0$ means $x^2 + 2(\frac p2)x + (\frac p2)^2 - (\frac p2)^2 +w = 0$ means $(x + \frac p2)^2 - (\frac p2)^2 + w = 0$.

Comment: " I don't see how we can divide it by 2 and then subtract its square."  You don't just divide by 2 and subtract its square.  You divide *and multiply* by 2.  You can *always* do $w = k*(\frac wk)$ the only question is will it help you.  And you *add* *and* subtract the square. You can always do $w = w + k - k$.  The only qusestion is will it help you so $x^2 + mx +K = x^2 + 2(\frac m2) x+K = x^2 + 2(\frac m2)x  +(\frac m2)^2 - (\frac n2)^2 + K$ are all legal moves. But do they help us? $x^2 + 2(\frac m2)x  +(\frac m2)^2 - (\frac n2)^2 +K =(x + \frac m2)^2 -(\frac n2)^2 + K$.  Yes. Yes they do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "I just don't understand *why* we can complete the square."

The best way to see why it works, is to see a pictorial representation of what is going on, see:

[image: Complete the square]

The $x^2$ term is a square with both sides of length $x$. The $bx$ term is a rectangle with one side of length $x$ and one side of length $b$. When you divide by two you are splitting the $bx$ rectangle in two parts with still a side of length $x$ and the other side is now $\frac b2$.

When you place both rectangles as shown on the picture there is only a small square with sides of length $\frac b2$ missing. This small square has area $\frac {b^2}{4}$ and it is this part that you need to "*complete the square*".

If you have a term $a\ne 1$ in $ax^2+bx+c$ then you have to first "get it off" to get a square with both sides of length $x$. In that case the rectangle you get still has a side of length $x$ but its other side is now $\frac ba$ and this makes the area of the tiny missing square equal to $\frac {b^2}{4a}$.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to get on one side of the equation a term that is a square.  Then you take the square root on both sides of the equation (noting that there is a positive and a negative solution) to achieve the final solution.

Comment: This explains how to complete the square. I now that already. The question asks how is line 3 possible?

Comment: @ThisGuy Well, it's wrong anyway, as are many of the other lines, so you're not going to understand until you're trying to understand something correct in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The third line is wrong because you have added $\frac {b^2}{4a^2}$ and subtracted $\frac {b^2}{a^2}$.  When you go from the fourth line to the fifth line you are not taking the square root correctly.  You lost a $\pm$ sign on the left and the right is not the square root of the line above.  You seem to be thinking $\sqrt{x-y}=\sqrt x \pm \sqrt y$, which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$

$x^2 + \frac ba x + \frac c a= 0$

Now we notice that $x^2 + \frac ba x +....$ looks like the start of $x^2 + 2kx + k^2 = (x+k)^2$.  Can we get it into that format by adding and subtraction things?  We ne $x^2 + 2kx + k^2 + ...stuff ... = x^2 + \frac ba x + .... different stuff...$  So we kind of nee $2k $~ $\frac ba$...

$x^2 + 2\frac b{2a}x + \frac ca = 0$

$x^2 + 2\frac b{2a} + (\frac b{2a})^2 - (\frac b{2a})^2 + \frac ca = 0$

$(x + \frac b{2a})^2 - (\frac b{2a})^2 + \frac ca = 0$

And from there it all comes out in the wash.

Example $x^2 + 16x + 15 = 0$

$x^2 + 2*8x + 15 =0$

$x^2 + 2*8x + 64 - 64 + 15 = 0$

$(x^2 + 2*8x + 64) -64 + 15 = 0$

$(x +8)^2 - 64 +15=0$

$(x+8)^2 - 49 = 0$

$(x+8)^2 = 49$

$(x + 8) = \pm 7$

$x = -8 \pm 7$.

===== Old answer =====

One thing, you have a typo on line 2:

But

$ax^2 +bx + c = 0$

$x^2 + \frac bax + \frac ca = 0$

$x^2 + \frac bax + googadee_bob - googadee_bob + \frac ca = 0$.

($anything + 0 = anything$ and $googadee_bob - googadee_bob = 0$.  We can always do this... Now *why* we would *want to is another story....)

$x^2 + \frac ba x + \frac {b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac ca = 0$

(If we can do it for $googadee_bob$ we can do it for $\frac {b^2}{4a^2}$.  But why we would *want* to....)

$(x^2 + \frac ba x + \frac {b^2}{4a^2}) - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac ca = 0$

$(x^2 + 2\frac b{2a} x + (\frac b{2a})^2) - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac ca = 0$

(Let $M = \frac b{2a}$.)

$(x^2 + 2M + M^2) - - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac ca = 0$

(we know $(x + M)^2 = x^2 + 2M + M^2$)

$(x + M)^2 -\frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac ca = 0$

(Oh, *that's* why we wanted to do it)

$(x + M)^2 = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac ca= \frac {b^2}{4a^2} - \frac {4ac}{4a^2}=\frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2} $

$x + M = \frac{\pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$

(Okay lets get $M$ back into $\frac b{2a}$ form)

$x + \frac b{2a} = \frac{\pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$

$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$

Comment: I can't change it but on the 4th from the end line, shouldn't it be $x + M = \frac{\pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$

Comment: Yeah... it's a formatting error.